# Why do indices after 5 print altered and truncated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

```
gallows = [
'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|       |
|       |
|      
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|     __|
|       |
|      
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|     __|__
|       |
|      
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|     __|__
|       |
|      /
|     /
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       O
|     __|__
|       |
|      / \
|     /   \
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
'''
---------
|       |
|       X
|     __|__
|       |
|      / \
|     /   \
|
|
|
---------------
''']

counter = 0

for i in range(len(gallows)):
    print(gallows[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Partial code that is included in a hangman game I am creating for fun.  When printing index 6 and 7, the format of the figure is messed up, and shortened by two lines.  Is python simply truncating the characters in the list due to the length of each index?  I haven't been able to figure out what is happening, or how to get around it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The special character `\` has to be escaped, write `\\` instead:

```
'''
---------
|       |
|       X
|     __|__
|       |
|      / \\
|     /   \\
|
|
|
---------------
'''
```

Comment: Yup.  Spent too long finding a complex solution for a very simple problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: To add to the solution the `\ `character is the new line character. If you are writing on a good IDE you should see the `\ ` as a different colour from the rest of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Put an `r` at the beginning of each frame

```
gallows = [
r'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|
|
|
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|       |
|       |
|      
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|     __|
|       |
|      
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|     __|__
|       |
|      
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       |
|       O
|     __|__
|       |
|      /
|     /
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       O
|     __|__
|       |
|      / \
|     /   \
|
|
|
|
---------------
''',
r'''
---------
|       |
|       X
|     __|__
|       |
|      / \
|     /   \
|
|
|
---------------
''']

counter = 0

for i in range(len(gallows)):
    print(gallows[counter])
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add r to the string like this:

```
r'''
---------
|       |
|       X
|     __|__
|       |
|      / \
|     /   \
|
|
|
---------------
'''
```